# How to get installed application with owner (user) on AIX?

Tags: package, aix, owner

I am using "rpm -qa --qf" to retrieve list of installed applications/packages on AIX with corresponding versions. However, I would also need the corresponding user/owner for each of these applications.

Can anyone please confirm how this can be obtained using rpm OR any other utility available in AIX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might add a Redhat Linux tag since (I'm guessing) if it can be done, it will be some option to rpm which comes from Redhat.

Answer (score 0):

By default, RPM packages are not installed per user, they are installed system wide.  So username does not vary per package.

You could use the `--dbpath` option to RPM,  giving it a user's home directory and having it track packages installed relative to just that user (~//bin, etc), but this would be completely independent from the master package database.